# Why does the following shell sequence ends so quickly?

Tags: tty, cat

Let be the files `com` and `fic` whith the access rights defined in the following shell sequence:

```
$ cat com
if tty>/dev/null
    then read x
    else read x<fic
fi
echo $x
$ cat fic
abcd
$ ls -l com fic
-r-xr-xr-x  1 jmr    ens    70 Jan 22 09:41 com
-r--r--r--  1 jmr    ens    5 Jan 22 09:41 fic
$
```

Why does it stops at `echo $x` when `com` is launched (in foreground)? Shouldn't it read `fic` then?

Comment: Where are you trying to run `com`?

Comment: on a table with a sheet of paper and a pencil, this is the answer given by the book: *Exercices corrigés de programmation UNIX* by J.M. Rifflet

Comment: Also, when you launch `com` in the foreground it will have a tty, so will be in the `if` block, not the `else` so it will wait for input on `stdin`, if you execute it without a tty (for example `ssh localhost ./com`) it will read `fic`

Comment: Strictly speaking, unless an error happens, the last line will be `echo $x`, either way. Your question is probably "why is the script does not stop on the interactive `read`?"

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much my question...

Comment: It's not about the read in the loop! its about the fact that J.M. Rifflet says it stops as it is and do not do `$ cat fic`

Answer (score 5):

```sh
if tty>/dev/null ; then
    read x
else
    read x<fic
fi
```

means, that `fic` will only be read when `tty` returns an error. Which will happen when it finds that its `stdin` is not a terminal. Typically this happens either when the script is in a pipe or when you run it via `nohup`, or as a cron job, or remotely via `ssh -T`...

Using `[ -t 0 ]` as a condition is pretty much the same (and faster, since `[` aka `test` is usually a built-in these days).

Answer (score 1):

The com shell script, when executed in the foreground, stops on line:
    read $x
because it is waiting for an input on `read` on the actual `tty`.

If you type a line, the `read` will terminate and set this line to the variable `x`.